# Paragraph written from right to left

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is there is a way to tell an iText paragraph contents to write from right to left?

I know it can be done with ColumnText or a table, but I need it in a paragraph (multiple pages can be written).

Comment: are you looking setting the alignment from left to right?

Comment: @Dinup kandel yes, and also writing the text from right to left like in columnText.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL)

Answer (score 0):

Here is just an example.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A1.rotate(), 20, 20, 20, 20);
document.addTitle("YourReport");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
        new FileOutputStream("c:\\ITextTest.pdf"));
document.open();            
Paragraph TitleHeading = new Paragraph(targetFileName);
TitleHeading.setAlignment(writer.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);            
document.add(TitleHeading);
```